# What will be the minimum value of $abab$ (a 4 digit number) for its maximum number of factors?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> $abab$ is a **4 digit number** (example: $abab$ = 9595, 7878). When the value of $abab$ is
>   **minimum**, what will be its **maximum number of factors**?

Source: [Bangladesh Math Olympiad 2018 Junior Category](https://www.matholympiad.org.bd/)

Note that $a\ne b$

Comment: Isn't $1212$ the minimum?

Comment: I don't think the question makes sense as written. When the value of $abab$ is minimum, it is either $1212$ or $1111$ depending on whether $a=b$ is allowed. This doesn't have a "maximum number of factors" - it just has however many factors it has.

Comment: But I think the "maximum number of factors" is a must. Is there any way to prove a number that has maximum number of factors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick computer check shows that $7272$, $8484$ and $9696$ have the same (maximum) number of divisors ($24$):

{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 18, 24, 36, 72, 101, 202, 303, 404, 606, 
  808, 909, 1212, 1818, 2424, 3636, 7272},

{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 12, 14, 
  21, 28, 42, 84, 101, 202, 303, 404, 606, 707, 1212, 1414, 2121, 
  2828, 4242, 8484},

{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 24, 32, 48, 96, 101, 
  202, 303, 404, 606, 808, 1212, 1616, 2424, 3232, 4848, 9696}

so if I understand your question (which of these is *minimum*?), the answer is:  $7272$.

---

The original question did *not* state that the solution must be done by hand, but in that case, @MishaLavrov's approach (below) is the best:

Recognize that $abab = ab \cdot 101$, so the factors of $abab$ are maximized when $ab$ has the most factors.  It is a simple matter to find (by hand) that $72$, $84$ and $96$ have the same (maximum) number of factors.

The rest is easy.

Comment: This is probably the right way to read the question. (Since all numbers of the form $abab$ are multiples of $101$, it's also enough to just look for the minimum number $ab$ which has the maximum number of factors for a $2$-digit number.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov:  Yep... that's a good way to solve it.  (teeny +1)

Comment: Even calculators are not allowed in a Math Olympiad. So, how am I supposed to answer this question?

Comment: Solve it @MishaLavrov's way:  find two-digit numbers $ab$ that have the maximum number of factors.  That can be done without a calculator. Then just choose the minimum such $ab$.

Comment: I can't read the question any way other than to require that $abab$ itself be minimum, i.e. $abab=1010$. In that case, $1010=2\cdot 5\cdot 101$ has three factors. I note the question asks for factors, not divisors.